# Extract first word from UITextView

Tags: iphone, uikit, nsstring, uitextview

In my app I have a UILabel which is the title and a UITextView which is the description and I want the title UILabel to be the first word typed into the UITextView. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well your problem, this code might do the trick:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    NSString *text = _textView.text;
    NSArray *elements = [text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    if ([elements count] > 0)
    {
        _label.text = [elements objectAtIndex:0];
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work for English and some other languages that use spaces to separate words, but will fail for many others. To do this the "right" way, use CFStringTokenizer.